# Morbidity and comorbidity in Italian

Tags: translation, difference

I have consulted the mymemory.translated.net resource to look up the translation of the terms morbidity and comorbidity in Italian, and I have found the terms morbilità (with an"l" instead of with a "b", as morbidità would probably mean softness instead of presence of disease), and morbosità. I would like to know, what is the exact difference between the terms morbilità and morbosità? To what extent are these terms interchangeable? Also, the translation of comorbid seems to be comorbilità, but would comorbosità be an incorrect translation, or would it be an equally acceptable term?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 6):

When trying to translate technical terms (as is the case here) a good technique is to go to the corresponding Wikipedia page and see if it has a version in the desired language. Here it works perfectly for [*comorbidity*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comorbilit%C3%A0) but not so much for *morbidity* (that Wikipedia has unfortunately decided to fold into the page relative to *disease*).

However, looking in a dictionary we see that there are two possible translations, *morbilità* and *morbosità* and both of them have Wikipedia pages. Let us see what they say.

For [*morbilità*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morbilit%C3%A0)

> In statistica, la **morbilità** è il numero dei casi di malattia registrati durante un periodo dato in rapporto al numero complessivo delle persone prese in esame.

For [*morbosità*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morbosit%C3%A0)

> La **morbosità** è un indice della statistica sanitaria che esprime la frequenza di una malattia in una popolazione. È definito come il rapporto tra il numero di soggetti malati e la popolazione totale. [...] In epidemiologia il termine è tuttavia spesso impiegato come sinonimo di morbosità.

So it seems that, in the technical meaning, they are more or less interchangeable. *Morbosità* seems to be more widely used outside epidemiology, but we'd need an expert opinion to be sure.

I should also point out that *morbosità* has a second nontechnical meaning, also corresponding to a meaning of the word *morbidity*: the taste for macabre.

> **morbosità** s. f. [dal lat. *morbosĭtas -atis*]. – **1.** La qualità e la condizione dell’esser morboso, in senso proprio e soprattutto fig.: *la m. di certe passioni*; *la m. della madre verso il figlio*. **2.** In statistica, il rapporto percentuale tra il numero dei casi di una determinata malattia e la popolazione in cui si è verificata (lo stesso quindi che *morbilità*): *una zona ad alta morbosità*.
>
> **morbosità**  f. n. [from lat. *morbosĭtas -atis*]. – **1.** The quality and condition of being morbose, literally and more often figuratively: *la m. di certe passioni*; *la m. della madre verso il figlio*. **2.** In statistics, the percentage of the number of cases of a certain illness and the population in which they happened (hence the same of *morbilità*): *una zona ad alta morbosità*.
>
> (from the [*Vocabolario Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/morbosita/))